# Android Gmail : Press Reply, will show Dialog to select Gmail or my App to Compose

Tags: android, dialog, gmail, text-editor, confirm

I am now developing a composer (only text editor to compose a message).
What I want is when user press "reply" on Android's Gmail app, it shows a dialog for user to choose my text editor or gmail to write the message. 
how to do that?

Comment: I guess no answer for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are choosen by chooser-dialog when you have corresponding IntentFilters in your Manifest for that entry

Like for IME you need something like "BIND_INPUT_METHOD"(if i remember) .

Likewise I think you will need something similar for your app's Manifest.
So you can try these IntentFilters

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="mailto" />
</intent-filter>
```

guess this will work....

Comment: Hi @Vincent, I'm sorry but it does not work on me. Gmail directly open Gmail composer right away eventhough I already added these lines on android manifest. Maybe I did not write it right..should I add these line after intent-filter (so create a new intent filter tag) or should I edit the original intent-filter and add the lines (including the intent-filter tags)?